# Setting cookie doesn't persist between web requests

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I've created a brand new ASP.Net 4.6 MVC project, and have tried to set a value in the Requests Cookies collection and retrieve it in the next request. I'm using cookies because `Session` isn't available yet within the `Application_BeginRequest` method. Using the following code, the cookie value I ask for is null in every request I make, despite setting it.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        var cookie = this.Request.Cookies.Get("Foo");
        string value = cookie?.Value;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            cookie = new HttpCookie("Foo", "Bar");
            cookie.Expires = System.DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1);
            this.Request.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
    }

    protected void Application_EndRequest()
    {
        var cookie = this.Request.Cookies.Get("Foo");
        string value = cookie?.Value;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? All of the posts I've seen relating to cookies shows setting/getting them in this fashion, with `Request.Cookies.Get`/`Request.Cookies.Add`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting the cookie in this code you are only reading it, I made this same mistake. Use this

```
this.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

instead of

```
this.Request.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

You should now see it in google chromes Application -> Cookies for your site

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get state for each request, you have to do in `Application_AcquireRequestState`

Your `Application_AcquireRequestState` implementation should be :

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cookie = this.Request.Cookies.Get("Foo");
        string value = cookie?.Value;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            cookie = new HttpCookie("Foo", "Bar");
            cookie.Expires = System.DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1);
            this.Request.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had tried that, but it was never hit. I'd set a break point and VS would never break in that method.

Comment: I ended up fixing it by setting my cookie with the Response instead of the Request. The cookie value was available for me in the next request. Thanks tho

Comment: After hitting Application_BeginRequest, it should go to Application_AcquireRequestState

Comment: But I would recommend to use Application_AcquireRequestState for your purpose

Comment: I've just tried in VS 2015 IIS Express and it's working fine